# Office Add-in Ribbon - Checkbox

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

I'm working on an Outlook 365 Add-in. I have a working Manifest XML that shows an icon with the icon responding to a function click. How would I go about adding a checkbox to the compose new email ribbon to the right of the button similar to the example below? I know how to do this VSTO, but looking how to do this using the Office 365 Add-in Javascript implementation. Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: If you can help me understand what is the exact scenario you are trying to achieve, I can try to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Sure, I wanted to allow users to check a box to toggle on/off adding/removing a predefined BCC + show/hide the add-in pane on the right hand side.

Comment: The feature you suggested are currently not part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) are considered when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 1):

The developer wants to create a ribbon button with checkboxes on it. Unfortunately - this is not possible through office-js manifests.

You can check the add-in commands (ribbon buttons for office-js) documentation from here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/design/add-in-commands.md

From the documentation:

> **Control types**
>
> - Simple buttons - trigger specific actions.
> - Menus - simple menu
>     dropdown with buttons that trigger actions.

That capability doesn't exist today in office-js framework.